# How to solve Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 1

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I am trying to rewrite the following text into an url

`$string="Jean-Maxime . Thäre! wouldn't %bé#äny ąśćłóżźń. OEß L'élève

 &nbsp; %   áàâãªä que voici est allé voir ça. Ils ont découvert où
 elles avaient cachées la Sainte Bible ?! <h3>\"Je suis riche\"</h3> ";`

and I have 3 functions but somehow it return the following error for one of the functions **Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 1**

The server says the error is on this line

```
$text =preg_replace(array_keys($utf8), array_values($utf8), $text);
```

Here are my 3 functions:

```
function normaliser($string)
{
    $string = strip_tags(mb_strtolower($string));




    return preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}
################################################################################
//On enleve les accents et on normalise le texte
function enlever_accents($text) {

     $utf8 = array(
    '/[áàâãªä]/u'   =>   'a',
    '/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/u'    =>   'A',
    '/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u'     =>   'I',
    '/[íìîï]/u'     =>   'i',
    '/[éèêë]/u'     =>   'e',
    '/[ÉÈÊË]/u'     =>   'E',
    '/[óòôõºö]/u'   =>   'o',
    '/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/u'    =>   'O',
    '/[úùûü]/u'     =>   'u',
    '/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u'     =>   'U',
    '/ç/u'           =>   'c',
    '/Ç/u'           =>   'C',
    '/ñ/u'           =>   'n',
    '/Ñ/u'           =>   'N',
    '/[\²&~#"\'{(\[|`_\^\)°+=}*;:!§?%’,;]/u'    =>   '', //J'enleve les caracteres speciaux
    '/–/u'           =>   '-', // UTF-8 hyphen to "normal" hyphen
    '/[’‘‹›‚]/u'    =>   ' ', // Literally a single quote
    '/[“”«»„]/u'    =>   ' ', // Double quote
    '/ /u'           =>   ' ', // nonbreaking space (equiv. to 0x160)
);




     $text =preg_replace(array_keys($utf8), array_values($utf8), $text);

    $text =mb_strtolower($text);


    return  normaliser($text);
}

######################################################################### 

//Fonction qui permet de reecrire les urls
function reecrire_url_titre($string) {


   $string=  enlever_accents($string);
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
```

**The problem is mainly with this**

```
function enlever_accents($text) {

    $utf8 = array(
        '/[áàâãªä]/u'   =>   'a',
        '/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/u'    =>   'A',
        '/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u'     =>   'I',
        '/[íìîï]/u'     =>   'i',
        '/[éèêë]/u'     =>   'e',
        '/[ÉÈÊË]/u'     =>   'E',
        '/[óòôõºö]/u'   =>   'o',
        '/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/u'    =>   'O',
        '/[úùûü]/u'     =>   'u',
        '/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u'     =>   'U',
        '/ç/u'           =>   'c',
        '/Ç/u'           =>   'C',
        '/ñ/u'           =>   'n',
        '/Ñ/u'           =>   'N',
        '/[\²&~#"\'{(\[|`_\^\)°+=}*;:!§?%’,;]/u'    =>   '', //J'enleve les caracteres speciaux
        '/–/u'           =>   '-', // UTF-8 hyphen to "normal" hyphen
        '/[’‘‹›‚]/u'    =>   ' ', // Literally a single quote
        '/[“”«»„]/u'    =>   ' ', // Double quote
        '/ /u'           =>   ' ', // nonbreaking space (equiv. to 0x160)
    );


    $text = htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

     $text =preg_replace(array_keys($utf8), array_values($utf8), $text);

    $text =mb_strtolower($text);


    return  $text;
}
```

Please How to solve Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 1 ?

Comment: Use the `/u` modifier in the regex, with all `preg_replace` calls. Also, use `mb_strtolower` instead of `strtolower`

Comment: I just edited it and added the following ```preg_replace('/~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i/u', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));``` and  ```preg_replace('/-+/u', '-', $string);`` and used mb_strtolower. Maybe i am missing something. Please can you show me ?

Comment: Yes, `'/ç/'           =>   'c',`, etc.

Comment: I just did that but i am still facing challenges. Can you please copy the edited code above and show me where i am missing in in answers ? I will mark it as answer if it is correct and works because i am still getting the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To replace accented letters with PHP, the way isn't to use a regex (several in your case), but to use `iconv`:

```
$yourstring = Normalizer::normalize($yourstring, Normalizer::NFC);
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_FR');
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $yourstring);
```

You need also to be sure the your string is at the beginning an UTF-8 encoded string. Otherwise, convert it before using `mb_convert`

Then to deal with other characters, all you need to do if I understand well you intention, is to do only one replacement and to trim:

```
$result = trim(preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]+~i', '-', $result), '-');
```

(put in the character class all characters you want to preserve)

---

```
function normaliser($str) {
    # convert letters with combining characters to a single unicode point
    $str = Normalizer::normalize($str, Normalizer::NFC);

    # transliterate unicode characters to ASCII
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_FR');
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str);

    # convert to lowercase (since your string is now an ascii string, no need to use mb_strtolower)
    $str = strtolower($str);

    # remove html tags
    $str = strip_tags($str);

    # TODO: - deal with html entities
    #       - replace unwanted characters with an hyphen
    #       - trim leading and trailing hyphens

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: That gives me the following ``Jean-Maxime . Th"are! wouldn't %b'e#"any a's'cl'oz'z'n. OEss L''el`eve   % 'a`a^a~aa"a que voici est all'e voir ca. Ils ont d'ecouvert o`u elles avaient cach'ees la Sainte Bible ?! `` Which is not that accurate and user readable

Comment: @JohnMax: I suspect that your accented letters are build with two characters instead of one (a non accented letter and a combining character), but you can solve that using intl normalizer before.

Comment: Ok. Please how to use intl normalizer on php 5.3. Cos this is what i got http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php but i am much new to it

Comment: @JohnMax: I added the "normalize" line in the code. Sometime the intl module isn't installed, check your php.ini to know that.

Comment: Thanks but i get this ``Fatal error: Class 'Normalizer' not found``

Comment: @JohnMax: install the intl module. (linux: `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`) (don't forget to restart apache after)